# Kendo UI Grid search as type example

Tags: search, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I would like to search datagrid in Kendo UI during typing into input field above the grid.

How can I do it?

Thanks for any advice.

Here is example of columns:

```
   $("#grid").kendoGrid({
            dataSource: dataPacket,
            filterable: true,
            pageSize: 10,
            pageable: true,
            sortable: true,
            reorderable: true,
            resizable: true,
            columnMenu: true,
            height: 550,
            toolbar: ["create", "save", "cancel"],
            columns: ["id", 
                      "username", 
                      "name",
                      "surname", 
                      "email", 
                      {
                          field :"created", 
                          title : "Created at",
                          format: "{0:M/d/yyyy}",
                          parseFormats: ["dd-MM-yyyy"],
                          type: "date"
                      },
```

Comment: We need more background information. Columns and fields at least, and DataSource configuration might be useful.

Comment: I would like to search in whole dataset filled in from API in read event.

Comment: If you give me at least columns I can give you an example. Otherwise I'll give you only pseudo-code. What do you prefer?

Comment: I added some example to question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Kendo make this thing really easy for you, what is needed is to create a filter and pass it to the DataSource. 
http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/framework/datasource#methods-filter

However, this problem must be divided into two different tasks:

a) Capture the key events in the search box, **throttle** it and start the search "operation".

b) Build a filter and pass it to the DataSource.

So for throttling the keyboard events, we need a timeout. Or use the throttle function from underscorejs. Why? We don't wanna trigger a search operation on each key press. Only 250 milliseconds (this number is up to you) after the last keystroke.

Here is your sample HTML

```
<input type="text" id="search" />
```

Here is your sample script. I wrap everything as a self calling function as you don't wanna create a mess declaring global variables.

```
(function($, kendo){

    // ID of the timeout "timer" created in the last key-press
    var timeout = 0;

    // Our search function 
    var performSearch = function(){

        // Our filter, an empty array mean "no filter"
        var filter = [];

        // Get the DataSource
        var dataSource = $('#grid').data('kendoGrid').dataSource;

        // Get and clean the search text.
        var searchText = $.trim($('#search').val());

        // Build the filter in case the user actually enter some text in the search field
        if(searchText){

            // In this case I wanna make a multiple column search so the filter that I want to apply will be an array of filters, with an OR logic. 
            filter.push({
                logic: 'or',
                filters:[
                    { field: 'username', operator: 'contains', value: searchText },
                    { field: 'name', operator: 'contains', value: searchText },
                    { field: 'surname', operator: 'contains', value: searchText },
                    { field: 'email', operator: 'contains', value: searchText }
                ]                  
            });               
        }

        // Apply the filter.
        dataSource.filter(filter); 
    };

    // Bind all the keyboard events that we wanna listen to the search field.
    $('#search').on('keyup, keypress, change, blur', function(){

          clearTimeout(timeout);
          timeout = setTimeout(performSearch, 250);
    });

})(window.jQuery, window.kendo);
```

Bottom-line: Make sure you are using the right DataSource configuration.

If you configured **serverFiltering = true**, this filtering logic will be part of your Ajax request, so your server will have to interpret and perform the filtering on server-side.

In case you configured  **serverFiltering = false** all this filtering logic will be evaluated on client side using JavaScript (damn fast!). And in this case, the **schema** (what data-type is expected on each column) must be also well-configured.

Comment: Thanks, I thought that Kendo has some build-in function to do this lik e some others DataGrid widgets. I try it to do by this way.

Comment: @redrom in this case you need some simpler solution, you can use the column menu "filter" feature. http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/documentation/api/web/grid#configuration-columnMenu-filterable it will give you some sort of filtering functionality *per-column*. It's pretty much ugly though, but gets the job done.

Comment: Many thanks for your code. I found that $('#search').on('keyup.. is not working under scope function in Angular JS, could You please provide example for Angular JS?

Comment: Nicely worked for me.